# Can a failed Airflow DAG Task Retry with changed parameter

Tags: python, pipeline, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

With Airflow, is it possible to restart an upstream task if a downstream task fails? This seems to be against the "Acyclic" part of the term DAG. I would think this is a common problem though.

**Background**

I'm looking into using Airflow to manage a data processing workflow that has been managed manually.

There is a task that will fail if a parameter x is set too high, but increasing the parameter value gives better quality results. We have not found a way to calculate a safe but maximally high parameter x. The process by hand has been to restart the job if failed with a lower parameter until it works.

The workflow looks something like this:

Task A - Gather the raw data

Task B - Generate config file for job

Task C - Modify config file parameter x

Task D - Run the data manipulation Job

Task E - Process Job results

Task F - Generate reports

**Issue**

If task D fails because of parameter x being too high, I want to rerun task C and task D. This doesn't seem to be supported. I would really appreciate some guidance on how to handle this.

Comment: Is it possible to merge task C and D as a single task ?.

Comment: Not directly. I suppose a solution would be to have a wrapper python script that runs C and D, and have that script be the single task.

Comment: Also see: [How to persist a value during airflow retry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54668052/3679900)

Answer (score 2):

*First of all: that's an excellent question, I wonder why it hasn't been discussed widely until now*

---

I can think of two possible approaches

1. **Fusing `Operators`**: As pointed out by [**@Kris**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6332463/kris), [Combining `Operators` together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53308306/fusing-operators-together) appears to be the most obvious workaround
2. **Separate *Top-Level* `DAG`s**: Read below

---

**Separate Top-Level DAGs approach**

Given

- Say you have tasks A & B
- A is upstream to B
- **You want execution to resume (retry) from A if B fails**

(Possibile) Idea: **If your'e feeling adventurous**

- Put tasks A & B in separate *top-level* `DAG`s, say DAG-A & DAG-B
- At the end of DAG-A, trigger DAG-B using `TriggerDagRunOperator`

  - In all likelihood, you will also have to use an `ExternalTaskSensor` after `TriggerDagRunOperator`
- In DAG-B, put a `BranchPythonOperator` after Task-B with [`trigger_rule=all_done`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models.py#L2431)
- This `BranchPythonOperator` should branch out to another `TriggerDagRunOperator` that then invokes DAG-A (again!)

---

Useful references

- [Fusing Operators Together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53308306/fusing-operators-together)
- [Wiring Top-Level DAGs together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51325525/wiring-top-level-dags-together)

---

**EDIT-1**

Here's a much simpler way that can achieve similar behaviour

[How can you re-run upstream task if a downstream task fails in Airflow (using Sub Dags)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49008716/3679900)

Comment: **[1]** Once you break down tasks to separate DAGs, you could also explore `SubDagOperator` **[2]** In idea above, the *clutter* could be reduced by say, making TASK-B itself a `BranchPythonOperator` (and similarly other things too)