# Can we somehow using some hack implement circular movement of tasks in an airflow? Mostly its not possible but is there any way around?

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I know that it just allows acyclic movement but is there any way around like we could programmatically implement it?

Comment: Read the section titled [Separate Top-Level DAGs approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54229812/3679900). I believe it can be achieved with single DAG also (not that i would recommend doing so)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to make the DAG re-trigger itself:

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.dagrun_operator import TriggerDagRunOperator

DAG_ID = 'cycle_dag'

default_args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2011, 1, 1, 1, 1),
}

with DAG(
    dag_id=DAG_ID,
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval="@once",
    catchup=False,
    max_active_runs=1,  # We want only one running DAG at a time
) as dag:
    do = PythonOperator(
        task_id='do_some_work', python_callable=sleep, op_args=[10]
    )
    repeat = TriggerDagRunOperator(task_id='repeat', trigger_dag_id=DAG_ID)

do >> repeat
```

Comment: This will re-trigger the dag from the first task right? can we somehow trigger the dag from a specified task?

Comment: @Gursheesh the DAG will be re-triggered by the last task (`TriggerDagRunOperator`). You can put this operator anywhere in your DAG and re-trigger the DAG after any specified task. Please extend your initial description and add details, because it is not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: What i want to do is, in a specific condition i want to go back to some previous state and re-run it from there

Comment: And what i can understand here is, the task having TriggerDagRunOperator will re-trigger the dag from the 1st task right?

Comment: @Gursheesh OK, then, it looks like y2k-shubham already gave you a reference to the solution.